# VBA Crashing Around 700 Iterations - Excel keeps crashing when I try to run this VBA loop out to 1000s, (650 is safe) iterations. Any thoughts?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, crash

```vb
  Sub LottoSearch()
   Dim stopRunUp As Integer
   stopRunUp = 0
    For i = 2 To 1000

     lottoNum = Cells(i, 3).Value

      If lottoNum = 3957481 Then
        Cells(2, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(2, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(2, 8).Value = lottoNum
        MsgBox ("Congratulations " + Str(Cells(2, 6).Value) + " " + Str(Cells(2, 7).Value))
      End If

      If lottoNum = 5865187 Then
       Cells(3, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(3, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
       Cells(3, 8).Value = lottoNum
      End If

     If lottoNum = 2817729 Then
       Cells(4, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(4, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
       Cells(4, 8).Value = lottoNum
     End If

     If lottoNum = 2275339 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
       Cells(5, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(5, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
       Cells(5, 8).Value = lottoNum
       stopRunUp = 1
     End If

     If lottoNum = 5868182 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
       Cells(5, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(5, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
       Cells(5, 8).Value = lottoNum
       stopRunUp = 1
     End If

     If lottoNum = 1841402 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
       Cells(5, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       Cells(5, 7).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
       Cells(5, 8).Value = lottoNum
       stopRunUp = 1
     End If

   Next i

 End Sub
```

I have double checked that I have an updated version of Excel (Microsoft 365).

Have ensured there is plenty of memory space and CPU.

Have tried in Excel business and home to see if anything is different, no luck.

The code works so long as my for loop limit is 650 or lower.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reading and writing cells consume PC resources and take time. Loading data into an array and processing data in memory improves efficiency.
- Using `ElseIf` is better than using multiple `If` statements.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub LottoSearch()
    Dim stopRunUp As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long, lottoNum
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    lastRow = 1000
    stopRunUp = 0
    Set rngData = Range("A1:H" & lastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        lottoNum = arrData(i, 3)
        If lottoNum = 3957481 Then
            arrData(2, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(2, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(2, 8) = lottoNum
            MsgBox ("Congratulations " + Str(arrData(2, 6)) + " " + Str(arrData(2, 7)))
        ElseIf lottoNum = 5865187 Then
            arrData(3, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(3, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(3, 8) = lottoNum
        ElseIf lottoNum = 2817729 Then
            arrData(4, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(4, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(4, 8) = lottoNum
        ElseIf lottoNum = 2275339 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
            arrData(5, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(5, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(5, 8) = lottoNum
            stopRunUp = 1
        ElseIf lottoNum = 5868182 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
            arrData(5, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(5, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(5, 8) = lottoNum
            stopRunUp = 1
        ElseIf lottoNum = 1841402 And stopRunUp = 0 Then
            arrData(5, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrData(5, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrData(5, 8) = lottoNum
            stopRunUp = 1
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Also sorry if my formatting was difficult to read. Very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

@Taller's answer is excellent and correct.
However, that could be taken a step even further to remove the need for `ElseIf` statements, by storing winning numbers in an array.
Then you use 'Nested Loops' (loops within loops) to check each result against each possible winning number.

While the below code isn't much shorter than the original I modified from, it makes it easier to read (all possible winning numbers are stored next to each other) and to add / remove more winning numbers in the future.

```
Sub LottoSearch()
    Dim stopRunUp As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long, lottoNum
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, a As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    lastRow = 1000
    stopRunUp = 0

    'Store Winning numbers in an array
        'With StopRunup and MsgBox properties also in arrays
    Dim arrWinners(), arrStopRunup(), arrMsgBox()
        'Arrays must be the same length!
    arrWinners = Array(3957481, 5865187, 2817729, 2275339, 5868182, 1841402)
    arrStopRunup = Array(False, False, False, True, True, True)
    arrMsgBox = Array(True, False, False, False, False, False)

    Set rngData = Range("A1:H" & lastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value

    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        lottoNum = arrData(i, 3)
        'Loop through winning numbers and check if they match.
        For j = LBound(arrWinners) To UBound(arrWinners)
            If lottoNum = arrWinners(j) And (stopRunUp = 0 Or arrStopRunup(j) = False) Then
                a = arrData(IIf(arrStopRunup(j), 5, j + 2)) 'working out which row to store in
                arrData(a, 6) = arrData(i, 1)
                arrData(a, 7) = arrData(i, 2)
                arrData(a, 8) = lottoNum
                If arrMsgBox(j) Then MsgBox "Congratulations " + Str(arrData(i, 1)) + " " + Str(arrData(i, 2))
                If arrStopRunup(j) Then stopRunUp = 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Of course, there's no objectively right or wrong way to do this, and if your code works then nobody is complaining. You mentioned you're new to this so I thought I'd add my tips!

TLDR; Arrays are awesome, nested loops are also cool, use both to avoid repeating an instruction wherever possible.